# Postgress query returning object instead of string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, discord.js

Hi I'm currently working with postgres along with with node.js and discord.js. I'm trying to get some data from the levels table which is a user id (a string of numbers). I'm able to query the id in the console fine however I'm returning `[object Object]` when running the command !id in Discord.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
module.exports = new Command({
name: "id",
description: "Gets an id",
async run(message, args, client){
    try{
        const res = await pool.query('SELECT user_id FROM levels WHERE guild_id = $1 AND user_id = $2', [message.guild.id, message.author.id]) 
        console.log(res.rows[0]) // returns the query fine in the console 
        result = res.rows[0] 
        message.channel.send(`${result}`) // returns a `[object Object]` when invoking command

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
        

}})
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `rows[0]` is a single row. A row is an object. Therefore this is expected behaviour. I assume this is using the `pg` module - see the documentation: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries "By default node-postgres reads rows and collects them into JavaScript objects with the keys matching the column names and the values matching the corresponding row value for each column." In your case, if you just want the value, then read the `user_id` property on that row.

Comment: Ah, I see  my mistake.I  guess it's not rows Im wanting but just the value of `user_id`. However, I found that I can do `JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]);` to return the object as a string which does in fact show me the row `{"user_id":"1234"}` .  I'm just wanting to get the value 1234 for example.

Comment: Just do `rows[0].user_id` then. Though you may want to test that `rows[0]` isn't undefined first.